# Edit gps recorded track

Tags: gps, garmin

I'm using Garmin Fit for my phone. On a long ride my phone went out of power and didn't manage to record the last of the track. I've uploaded the first part of the ride to Garmin Connect and can export the ride to gpx.

My question is
Please help me find a online-service that allows me to:

Manually edit and finish my route using an editor with "stick to road" functionality

Set the time for the new points, so I will get an average speed for the last part of the ride and the total time will be correct (I know that one).

Export the result to gpx or another convertable format, to upload to Garmin Connect.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but you may get better answers on gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: there's also the Garmin forums themselves. I've put together a bit of an answer below, but I have no idea whether I'm suggesting the best/easiest approach.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I don't know if there is a better way but I can offer a couple of suggestions.

There's a thread over on BikeRadar where someone is wanting to stitch two FIT files together, there's a suggestion to convert to TCX then manually merge the files using a text editor.

http://training.bikeradar.com/forum/longest-day-road-challenge-324/combining-separate-garmin-files-into-single-ride-152481

The posts within the thread indicate that the suggested method works.

Your case is obviously more complicated since you only have the one FIT file to start with.

So, you can manually create an activity to represent the last chunk of your ride. Garmin Connect supports this, although I don't know how functional it is. I do know that Garmin Connect will allow you to export your activity as a TCX, as I have done this. I can also suggest the site [rideWithGPS](http://rideWithGPS.com), which is my preferred portal. RWGPS will allow you to manually create an activity (including drawing the route on a Google map, let you to enter start/total times, and then export it (as TCX History).

You need to register with RWGPS but I don't think you need the pay account to do anything I've suggested.

Whichever way you choose, by the end of this process you should have two TCX files that you can merge.

In passing, [GPSies.com](http://www.gpsies.com/) is a great site for format-to-format conversions, although in your case you'll get your resulting TCX into Garmin Connect no problem.

One thing I would ask is that you let us know how you get on - I've never needed to do this but I'm a big Garmin user and there may come a day when I'll want to know this myself

Good luck!

Comment: You mention combining tracks. [How does one do that](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/17202/1683) if one is not using a Garmin device?

Comment: @2u2 well, the advice in that link advocates manual integration, also it is specific to TCX files (although GPX files are also xml so can also be modified manually). I suspect there is no tool which will just do this neatly for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create routes in [bikemap.net](http://bikemap.net) starting them by uploading a gpx file (exported from garmin connect) and adding the rest of required points. 
Once you have the route you should be able to upload that GPX to garmin connect, to be able to specify the times for the added points you would need to update the GPX file manually, they are just plain XML files, so it would be a tedious but not difficult process, but I wouldn't bother, total time is what you are mostly going to need.

Comment: By the way, I wrote a python script that joined different gpx files into one, but I don't think is what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/ Gps Visualizer was something that I used in the past.

Answer (score -2):

[GPX Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpxeditor/) seems like it should meet your needs.

Comment: What if the questioner isn't using windows? This appears to be windows-only software, and they were asking for an online service.