# Merge gpx files

Tags: gps

[How can I merge two GPX files into one?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17202/how-can-i-merge-two-gpx-files-into-one)

Read the above link but my gpx files do not seem to have this in them:

> Copy all the stuff between Open the second GPX file in a text editor. Copy all the stuff between `<trk>` and `</trk>` inclusive

I exported my ViewRanger file and saved the gpx file then opened in Windows Notepad. There is no `<trk>` and `</trk>` anywhere.

The first line of the file, opened in Notepad is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" version="1.0" creator="ViewRanger - http://www.viewranger.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

See this dropbox link for one of the files:-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7i5afte16zel6n/End%20to%20End%20-%20Day%201%20-%20Lands%20Ends%20to%20St%20Just.gpx?dl=0

I need to merge 18 files (Lands End to John O Groats)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So if you search for "trk" in the file, nothing is there?

Comment: could be its not a track I suppose. Any chance you could put the files somewhere, and one of us can eyeball them?

Comment: Look further down in the file.  This is the xml header describing what the nature of the document.

Comment: What platform did you use to do the export? While I support the Rider_X comment and @Batman's question, it could also be that the EOL characters are wrong. Most Windows software expect CR/LF. This [link](http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html) says the export format is platform dependent.

Comment: Yes, spot on @PeteH. It turned out to be a route, that other people can follow.

Comment: well I made my suggestion and totally forgot to check back to look at the file. But that looks like a good answer @andy256, hopefully it helps the Op out

Answer (score 4):

Ok, Looking at the data you posted, you can see

> <rte>
>
> ...
>
> </rte>

These tags enclose the whole [GPX Route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format).

After the  tag comes the name. You can put what you like in between the second [ and the ]]:

> ```
> <name><![CDATA[End to End - Day 1 -  Lands Ends to St Just]]></name>
> ```

Then comes an ordered set of routepoints

> ```
> <rtept lat="50.066113" lon="-5.712081">
>   <name>1</name>
> </rtept>
> ```

You can construct a file starting with the first *three* lines

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>
> <gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" ...
>
> <rte>

Then add in all the routepoints from your various GPX files.

End with

> </rte>
>
> </gpx>

Hope that helps.

Comment: I will need to experiment; should be interesting as some routes have vast numbers of waypoints.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the dropbox file it appears to contain a **route**, rather than a **track**. I suspect something went wrong when you exported the file. If there are options on what to export, then you want to export the **track** rather than the route or waypoints or anything else.

This [Wikipedia article on GPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) has more details on GPX files which might help..

Comment: When I use the button "Export to GPX" I am only given the option to save file; can't select track or route.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I will be able to do what I really want.

My idea is to have an A3 print, or even an A2 print, of our whole route from Lands End to John O Groats, overlaid over a map of the UK.

I now have a gpx of the whole route

However the only place I can get a reasonable representation is on my tablet or phone.

This has to do with esthetics not information.

These two images, one a screenshot from my tablet and the other a screenshot from Google Earth show the esthetic differences:-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hngvvcru7ar3jtk/Screenshot_2014-10-24-10-23-25.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1rwy92svwwkjtyx/Google%20Earth.jpg?dl=0

The tablet screenshot would look ok, in a larger size (if I could scale the map detail as well i.e enlarging this just shows towns etc as blurs); the blue overlay gives enough detail without being over bearing. The line Google Earth shot is just too thick.

Comment: What do you want the big printout for?  a poster or something?

Answer (score 0):

Each member of our "End-to_end" ride would like an image to hang on their study wall; bearing in mind our, now, ages, some are not that au-fait with computers and prefer the technology in use when we did the ride i.e. 1998, even if I had to use the latest to produce the image. A2 ideally but A3 would do.